# different text depending on if user has liked a post

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have this if statement in my template to display different buttons depending on if a user had like a post. There are the same trigger link, url, and view, however the text either says "Like" or "Unlike" depending on if the user has previously liked that post or not. However it is not working, no errors, just not working.

likes is a `ManyToManyField` in the `UserPost` model.

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="single-post">
        <div class="post-header">
            <a class="link inline-block" href="{% url 'feed:post_detail' post.id %}">
                <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
            </a>

            <div class="post-interaction">
                {% if request.user.username in post.likes %}
                    <a class="link right-margin" href="{% url 'feed:post_like' post.id %}">
                        Unlike: {{ post.likes.count }}
                    </a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="link right-margin" href="{% url 'feed:post_like' post.id %}">
                        Like: {{ post.likes.count }}
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
                <a class="link right-margin" href="{% url 'feed:post_detail' post.id %}">
                    Comments: {{ post.comments.count }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% if post.image %}
            <img class="post-pic" src="{{ post.image.url }}">
        {% endif %}

        <p class="post-body more-top-margin">{{ post.post_body }}</p>

        <div class="divider"></div>

        <p class="message-hint post-meta">{{ post.author }}</p>
        <p class="message-hint post-meta">{{ post.post_date }}</p>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user == post.author or request.user.userprofile.user_level == 'admin' or request.user.userprofile.user_level == 'moderator' %}
            <a class="link right-margin" href="{% url 'feed:edit_post' post.id %}">
                Edit Post
            </a>
            <a class="link right-margin" href="{% url 'feed:delete_post' post.id %}">
                Delete Post
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Views.py:

```
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = 'account_login'
    model = UserPost
    template_name = 'feed/userpost_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 25
    queryset = UserPost.objects.all()
```

Model:

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='userpost',null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics',blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='post_likes')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-post_date']

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def likes_as_flat_user_id_list(self):
        return self.likes.values_list('user_id', flat=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Have you checked request.user.username and post.likes have the values you think they have?

Comment: yeah as far as I can tell they do. I am logged into the site and have liked a post, and in the admin I can see that my username is listed as liking that post.

Comment: Is that being passed to the template though? You should post the view from views.py. Also, is post.likes.count coming through OK?

Comment: I just posted the `view`. Yeah it is being passed though the view because the count of likes shows up and the `likes` field is part of the `UserPost` model which is the model being passed through that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a function to the UserPost model that exports the likes as a flat list, like this:

```
def likes_as_flat_user_id_list(self):
  return self.likes.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Not sure of the exact code required, as you have not posted your model.

You should then be able to do something like this in your template (again, might be slightly different depending on your models):

```
{% if request.user.id in post.likes_as_flat_user_id_list %}
```

**EDIT:**

It's probably more efficient to create a flat list of posts that the user liked and pass it in as a template argument, and check if the post id is contained in that list. The above code creates such a flat list for every post.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. What does `flat` do?

Comment: That worked, thank you! Just out of curiosity, why did it need to be `id` instead of `user_id`?

Comment: That's what the database field holding the user's id is named in the User model